# Django admin users table

Tags: django, django-admin

everyone!
I have a simple django application using sqlite database, in which I created superuser.
Now on admin page I can see that there is a users table.

The problem is that I can't find this table in my database. There is actually auth_user table but im not sure it's the same table that admin page shows.

Comment: Normally there should be a `appname_user` table (with `appname` the name of the app).

Comment: thats all I have

Comment: did you install the app in `INSTALLED_APPS`, make migrations and migrated the database?

Comment: Thanks you, I didn't  notice that!